# What is the origin of the term `SQS skein';

Tags: combinatorics, universal-algebra

What is the origin of the term `SQS skein'; it is a ternary operator that (in at least one avatar) arises in assigning algebras to (2,4) Steiner systems.  But skein module evidently comes up in knot theory. Is there a connection?